# Mail properties in Production - Jhipster 4.2.8

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail, jhipster

I have the following configuration of the mail account of my company in develop, which goes perfectly:

```
mail:
    host: smtp.xxx.es
    port: 587
    username: notifications-noreply@xxx.es
    password: xxxx
    protocol: smtp
    #tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
        auth: true
        from: notifications-noreply@xxx.es
        starttls.enable: true
        ssl.trust: smtp.xxx.es
```

I copy de same data from "application-dev.yml" to "application-prod.yml".

I make the deployment in Google Cloud.

It does not send me mails and the logs tells me the following:

```
: Email could not be sent to user 'joseluis.xxx@xxx.com': Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.xxx.es, 587; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out). Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.xxx.es, 587; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: The logs seem to be unequivocal, your service can't reach that mail server from Google Cloud. I would recommend you trying another mailing service (gmail, outlook...) and see if it works. If it does, the problem might be your mail server not being reachable from outside. If not, then you might need to configure Google Cloud for external connections.

Comment: With a gmail account if it goes correctly. My company account is hosted in "Dinahosting" in case it helps.

Comment: What happens if you try the same server with port 25 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) you can't send e-mail from your Google Cloud VM using port 587. So this has nothing to do with JHipster, it's a limitation from your cloud provider.

I personally use Mailgun, which uses port 2525 (which is allowed by Google Cloud), here is my configuration for https://start.jhipster.tech (a JHipster application that runs on Google Cloud):

```
spring:
    mail:
        host: smtp.mailgun.org
        port: 2525
        username: xxxxx@mg.jhipster.tech
        password: xxxxx
```

As Mailgun provides a generious free tier you can test this for free - in fact I use it in production and haven't paid anything yet!